# Create new column based on equality between existing columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

While it seems a trivial task, I haven't been able to find a tidy solution for it. I want to add a new (integer) column, `nCol` to a `dataframe`, the value of which is determined by comparing two existing columns (both String type) of the dataframe, `eCol1` and `eCol2`

something like:

```
df(nCol) = {
  if df(eCol1) == df(eCol2) then 1
  else 0
}
```

I believe it could be done with the help of [user-defined functions](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-sql-udfs.html) (UDFs). But isn't there tidier way for such a trivial task?

Comment: I've tried using when..otherwise methods of the [Column](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column) class but I'm unable to figure out how to test equality between two columns

Comment: `df.withColumn("nCol" , ($"KEY" === $"AMT").cast("int") )`

Comment: @philantrovert I would not recommend to cast a boolean to an int...

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Why is that? Can `$"col1" === $"col2"` return something else too apart from `true/false` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with Dataframe DSL `when/otherwise`, to test equality use `===`:

```
df
.withColumn("newCol", when(df(eCol1) === df(eCol2),1).otherwise(0))
```

Comment: The <=> operator provides null-safety and === provides type-safety. Is there a way to combine both?